# What is this menu in the bottom-left of Chrome inspector used for?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

Today I noticed a [small menu in the bottom left of Chrome Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESXwa.png). Upon clicking the dots, [this menu appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyGLL.png). When you select an option,  a tab is open in the bottom of inspector, but nothing changes on the page or in inspector.

Does anyone know what this menu is used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just discovered like 8 new worlds of DevTools features, my friend.

That whole section is called the Drawer. It's collapsed in your screenshot, which is why it seems like nothing is happening. Press Escape to expand it. You should be able to drag the bar to the right of the Search tab to adjust the Drawer's height.

Each of those menu items represents a different tab in the Drawer.

P.S. the Drawer collapses automatically when you're on the Console panel, if you also have the Console Drawer tab open. Otherwise DevTools would have to make sure that the two UIs stay in sync.

P.P.S. the Drawer should probably auto-expand when you click on a menu item, since you obviously want to use that tab. I think that's fixed in later versions of Chrome but I'll file a bug report if not.